# Custom Option Validation Dependent on another Custom Option

Tags: php, validation, dependencies, magento-1.7

I need a help to **apply a validation on custom option**, that is dependent on another custom option value.

Here is the image, which describes what I actually want :

[image]

Please suggest, I am using **Custom Options**, **Not Configurable Products**

Comment: What is the "product type" for the products which contains these options? If they are configurable products, then by default you can get this option.

Comment: @PavanKumar, No Bro, Its not Configurable Product, 

I am using Product > Custom Options

Comment: Then it is not possible. You have to use configurable products and create the attributes as explain below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of products, Configurable products type is the best option. First create the attribtues as shown then create the configurable products. Actually this can be set while you create those attributes like blouse size, length and customization. Go to the admin panel. Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes. Here search for your attribute that are using for those COnfigurable products. Then after edit those attributes and then you can see a field like "Required Values"-> Make this as Yes. Attaching a screenshot for ur reference.

[image]

Edit the other attributes as you required. Then make an ReIndex management and clear the cache. Refresh the frontend...Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks, But if you have 4000-5000 products,
Then I don't think so, that you would create 5-6 simple products per every configurable product... :)

Comment: Yes. As of my knowledge and my findings, You have to create simple products and you have to assign them to configurable product.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103680/how-to-create-dependent-attributes-in-magento