# Relational Dropdown/Select product attributes in Magento backend

Tags: php, magento, drop-down-menu

I'm developing a Magento store for a vehicle accessory company. There are a number of vehicle specific items that need Make/Model/Year attributes, however I can't find an extension that allows creation of relational attribute dropdowns - I need three dropdowns, whose options change dynamically depending on the previous dropdown selection, for example:

Dropdown A has four Vehicle Makes. Choosing a Make then populates the Model dropdown with a specific set of options and so on for the Year dropdown.

Is this possible in Magento? I've looked at some of the Make/Model/Year extensions, but they're all text inputs - too much room for input error by staff members. I've also tried VehicleFits but it isn't working/throws a lot of errors and it appears development has ceased.

I've searched high and low, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to create dependent product attributes directly or straight forwardly under Manage Attributes. But you can make your attributes depend on each other by creating Configurable products.

Lets say you have 2 colors (black and blue) and 2 sizes (L,XL) and you want to make your colors depend on sizes.

```
At first create 2 attributes size and color of type dropdown under Manage attributes and create the attribute options and values. and Assign it to the right attribute set.

Now create the simple products , lets say product A with size L and color Black and product B with color Blue and size XL.

Now create a configurable product lets say AB and associate these two simple products A and B. Save the product.
```

If the customer opens the product AB and if they choose size L they can find only color Black. This is how you can make your product attributes dependent on each other.

Source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103680/how-to-create-dependent-attributes-in-magento)

Or may be this is what you are looking for:
**http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dependent-custom-options-configurable.html**

Hope it helps.